# How to implement a generic way of saving different Dictionaries in Swift using NSKeyedArchiver?

Tags: generics, dictionary, swift, nskeyedarchiver

Sorry, if this is an easy question, but i couldn't find an answer for three days. I'm just new to Swift.

Problem: I'd like to use the Swift-Enum-Type as the KEY for different Swift-Dictionaries AND save this dictionaries using NSKeydArchiver in a generic way.

First of all I show some easy sample code for the enum and dictionaries (I know, I could integrate the dictionaries values directly into the enum declaration as rawValues, but this is not my problem, my problem is to SAVE the dictionary with NSKeydArchiver -> see function below)

```
// ------------------------------------------------------
// Enumerations and Dictionaries
// ------------------------------------------------------
enum helloOptions {
    case option1
    case option2
    case option3
}

enum someOtherEnum {
    case green
    case red
    case blue
}

var myDictionary01 : Dictionary<helloOptions, String> = [helloOptions.option1 : "Hello", helloOptions.option2 : "Welcome", helloOptions.option3 : "Nice to see you"]

var myDictionary02 : Dictionary<someOtherEnum, Int> = [someOtherEnum.green : 22, someOtherEnum.red : 11, someOtherEnum.blue : 999]
```

And here is my working implementation of a savingFunction, but unfortunately it is not a generic way, because I would need to implement this function many times for all Enums in the App.

```
func saveDictionary(myDictionary: Dictionary<helloOptions, AnyObject>, myFileName: String, myDataFolder: DataFolder) -> Bool {

    let completeDataPath = makeCompletePathToFile(myFileName, myDataFolder)

    let saveSuccess : Bool = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(myDictionary, toFile: completeDataPath)
    if !saveSuccess {
        println("Some problem saving Dictionary")
    }
    return saveSuccess
}
```

So I would like to have some generic Type of Enums, like "AnyEnumType" in order to use that function  in a generic way:

```
func saveDictionary(myDictionary: Dictionary<AnyEnumType, AnyObject>, myFileName: String, myDataFolder: DataFolder) -> Bool {
 ... 
}
```

But this - of course - causes a Compiler-Error "Use of undeclared type "AnyEnumType""

I tried a lot with typeAlias, with TypePlaceholders `<T : Hashable>` and so on, but I couldn't implement it.

How can I implement the function like this

```
func saveDictionary(myDictionary: Dictionary<AnyKeyType, AnyObject>, myFileName: String, myDataFolder: DataFolder) -> Bool { ..
}
```

by declaring this generic Type "AnyKeyType" is following the protocol Hashable, Equitable, ...
that enables me to use a String or a Enum.Member for Key ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
protocol EnumType {
    typealias RawType
    init?(rawValue: RawType)
    var rawValue: RawType { get }
}

enum Hello: String, EnumType {
    case Option1 = "Option1"
    case Option2 = "Option2"
}

func toArchivableDictionaryWithEnumerationKeys<E: EnumType, T>(dictionary: Dictionary<E, T>) -> Dictionary<E.RawType, T> {
    var result = Dictionary<E.RawType, T>()
    // Tried to use reduce here, but couldn't make it work
    for (key, value) in dictionary {
        result[key.rawValue] = value
    }
    return result
}

func fromArchivedDictionaryWithEnumerationKeys<E: EnumType, T>(dictionary: Dictionary<E.RawType, T>) -> Dictionary<E, T>? {
    var result = Dictionary<E, T>()
    for (key, value) in dictionary {
        if let enumKey = E(rawValue: key) {
            result[enumKey] = value
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    return result
}

let dict = toArchivableDictionaryWithEnumerationKeys([Hello.Option1: "Bob"])
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(dict)
let value = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as Dictionary<String, String>
if let unarchived: Dictionary<Hello, String> = fromArchivedDictionaryWithEnumerationKeys(value) {
    // Blah blah
}
```

Also, you should call your enumeration `HelloOptions` not `helloOptions`, and call the enumeration values `Option1`, not `option1`. All types in Swift should be capitalized. You'll notice that this convention is followed religiously by the designers of Swift. You should do so, too.